# Exception when I change to other scene in KorGE

Tags: kotlin, korge

> com.soywiz.korinject.AsyncInjector$NotMappedException: Class 'class ChooseCampaign (Kotlin reflection is not available)' doesn't have constructors RequestContext(initialClazz=class ChooseCampaign (Kotlin reflection is not available))

Above exception was threw when I compiled current code. And I dont know how fix it and what does it means.
My code:

```
textButton {
            position(0, 128)
            text = "Play"
            onClick {
                println("Play")
                launchImmediately {
                    sceneContainer.changeTo<ChooseCampaign>()
                }
            }
        }
```

How it fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Scenes in KorGE, you are using the `korinject` dependency injector indirectly.

And that injector requires manual mapping. If you are using Modules, you can configure those mappings at the `Module.init` method.

Check this sample: https://github.com/korlibs/korge-samples/blob/1771b7ca7f4440e1a368ff4b441e97bf62e08b8d/sample-scenes/src/commonMain/kotlin/main.kt#L15-L23

In your case, once you get the `Injector` instance, you can map a scene like this:

```
mapPrototype { ChooseCampaign(get()) }
```

You have to put as many `get()` as parameters your `ChooseCampaign` constructor has.

In the case you are not using modules, the place to put the mapping is different, and you need to get the `Injector` instance.

In your `suspend fun main() = Korge {` block, you have the `Stage` singleton injected. This is the root view that has a reference to the `Views` singleton.

So there you can just access the injector like this: `this.views.injector`

You can then map your scenes whenever you like, though I suggest you do to it at the beginning of the application.